# Browser not using the right font on certain server

Tags: css, fonts

I have some css like this:

```
font-family: "Open Sans Condensed",sans-serif;
```

And I'm having a hard time understanding how the displayed font is chosen. I always thought that the browser checks if the client has the first font installed, and if not, it uses the next font in the list. But now I've run into an issue where in my local and testing environments, using Firefox, the first font is used, but in production, using the the same browser on the same machine, the second font is chosen.

Why does the website use one font on one server and the other on a different server?

Is there any way to make it use the same font on all servers without @font-face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

This line was importing the font from Google:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

On the production server, they've decided to disallow all external requests like this, so it can't load the font. That's not the case on our other servers...

So I donwloaded the font from Google, generated webfonts at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, and then added the following css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use @font-face? It is well supported and invented to avoid this kind of problems. Please remember that for security reasons, does not work for subdomains in FF.

Comment: I ended up using @font-face, but originally, since it was working without it, I wanted to avoiding adding the font like this so as to help performance. It just didn't make sense to me that it would work on one server but not on another when I was using the exact same machine and browser to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the way the browser looks for the fonts in a local server vs live server. I had an issue before with naming a font "Open Sans Condensed" vs "OpenSans-Condensed" (it was a different font, but followed the same rule) which was the font filename. So maybe you could find the filename and add it to your 'font-family' tag.